# Can software released under the Boost software license be relicensed under the Zlib/Libpng License?

Tags: license-compatibility, relicensing, bsl, zlib-libpng

I came across a library on GitHub (now Zlib/Libpng licensed) that is a fork of a library that was originally released under the Boost software license.

Is it legitimate/legal to relicense boost software under the zlib license?

I guess the Boost license doesn't explicitly deny nor explicitly allow relicensing as far as I can tell, so I thought it was worth a question.

See: https://github.com/r-lyeh/units

Answer (score 2):

The [Boost license](http://www.boost.org/users/license.html) specifically states:

> The copyright notices in the Software and this entire statement, including
>   the above license grant, this restriction and the following disclaimer,
>   must be included in all copies of the Software, in whole or in part, and
>   all derivative works of the Software, unless such copies or derivative
>   works are solely in the form of machine-executable object code generated by
>   a source language processor.

So no, you can't relicense code under the Boost license.

The project in question is rather confused about its license though; the top of the [`README`](https://github.com/r-lyeh/units/blob/master/README.md) still says it's licensed using the Boost license, as does the [`library's code itself`](https://github.com/r-lyeh/units/blob/master/units.hpp). You could argue that the project as a whole uses the Zlib license, and includes Boost-licensed code, which is valid — but the code in question constitutes the entirety of the project...

Comment: When there is a difference between an asserted top level license and a license notice found in a code file and this is the only source of information, I received this advice from a lawyer: always consider the license that is closest to the code, which in most cases means the license found in the file vs. the top level license.

Comment: @PhilippeOmbredanne yes, thanks for clarifying that; that's what I do in practice — if I packaged this for Debian, I'd specify that the project's files use the Boost license in `debian/copyright`.